# programmatically execute alfresco rules

Tags: alfresco

I have created a rule programmatically in Java and attached with a space, its working fine whenever a new document is inserted into that space. But what if I already have some documents uploaded in the space and I want to run the Rule. I know i can do this via Explorer as defined in the following article.

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Ftasks%2Flibrary-folder-rules-run.html

But I want to achieve the same using Java code.

Does any one please suggest some solution.

:: I am using Alfresco enterprise 4.0.2

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to bind behaviours to policies instead if you are into java:

http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Policy_Component#Binding_Behaviour_to_a_Policy

My personal experience is that you as a developer get much more control over events in the repository using behaviours (opposed to rules). But maybe thats just me :)

Comment: Thanks, I have created a policy on "NodeServicePolicies.OnAddAspectPolicy" and executed my custom code on  "onAddAspect" method. now i have two questions/confusion. whenever i open my document the "onAddAspect" executes again, this should run only once when I am adding particular aspect, right? secondly I am ingestion bulk documents using code, will this approach makes any effects on ingestion performance?

Comment: Looks like this isn't run asynchronously .. ?

Comment: It should only be executed immediately after the aspect is added. I guess the performance will be reduced, to what grade depends on the performance of your custom code. It will (to my knowledge) be run synchronously.